# Is there a way to remove the StackEdit button from StackEdits toolbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stackedit

I am currently trying to integrate StackEdit.js into my site to use as an internal editor and I would ideally like to remove the StackEdit button from the toolbar of the editor if it is relatively straight forward to do so. This button links to StackEdits site.

My guess is that if it is optional to remove this button, it should be specified within the .openFile method, although I am relatively new to javascript/jquery so I could be wrong.

Here's my attempt at the code so far:

```
var articleHTML = document.getElementById('articleHTML');
var stackedit = new Stackedit();

stackedit.openFile({
    content: {
        text: "default body text"
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: Are you talking about the menu button, with the # on it?

Comment: Yes that's the one, it links to StackEdits website.

Comment: Yeah, Unfortunately you might be out of luck. That's their logo, and as with so many things that are free to use, the downside is that it usually comes with the logo plastered all over it. Even fully published unity games must display the unity logo in startup, even if the developer paid the licensing fee. Sucks, I know.

Comment: Thanks four help Chris, do you think it is possible to keep the logo but remove the hyperlink? I will try to contact the developer as I don't mind paying a fee.

Comment: Yeah, the developer is the best person to answer your questions. Don't offer to pay a fee up front though - they might just show you how to do it for nothing! Best of luck either way, though.